# Increment value of a property when value isn't defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add assign a value to a property in this fashion, but I can't seem to figure out how I could do this the correct way

```
let test = {}
test["Hi"] = 0 // would be inside a loop, so unless I add a check to see if "Hi" is a valid key in the object
test["Hi"] += 1 // What I want to happen

let test2 = {} // what I thought would work
test2["Hi"] += 1 || 0

console.log(test2) -- {Hi: NaN}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your goal right, try `test2.hi = (test2.hi || 0) + 1` (better to use dot notation when possible)

Comment: `test["Hi"] = (test["Hi"] || 0 ) + 1;` incremental assignment `+=` won't happen to an `undefined` value, so this is your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `test2["Hi"] += 1 || 0` what you ask to do is: if you can put to test2["Hi"] the value (test2["Hi"]+1) - do it. else, put there the value of test2["Hi"]+0. in your case, test2["Hi"] is undefined, so both of the options return NaN. if what you whant to do is test2["Hi"]+= 1 *OR* test2["Hi"] = 0, you can do it in another ways,

like:

```
    test2["Hi"] = test2["Hi"] + 1 || 0;
```

*OR*

```
    test2["Hi"] = test2["Hi"] ? test2["Hi"] += 1 : 0;
```

as you prefer. 
hope its help

Answer (score 0):

**@leak**, currently I will suggest you to use the below approach. Later, I will think about your approach and update the answer.

> Please comment if you have any suggestions for the improvement.

```
var test2 = {};
test2["Hi"] = test2["Hi"] != undefined? test2["Hi"] + 1:0
console.log(test2) //{Hi: 0};

test2["Hi"] = test2["Hi"] != undefined? test2["Hi"] + 1:0
console.log(test2) //{Hi: 1};

test2["Hi"] = test2["Hi"] != undefined? test2["Hi"] + 1:0
console.log(test2) //{Hi: 2};
```